# GCD doesn't work in custom keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, custom-keyboard

please can anyone help me? I have next problem. I created custom keyboard in xcode and want to use the GCD to load gifs async in array. But when i do this my app crash. My code

```
@implementation KeyboardViewController 

in viewDidLoad ()

dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("identifier", NULL);

    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{

        @synchronized (self.gifsArray){
            @autoreleasepool {
                for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_GIFS; i++) {
                    FLAnimatedImage *gifImage = [[FLAnimatedImage alloc] initWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i] ofType:@"gif"]]];
                    [self.gifsArray addObject:gifImage];
            }

        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please show the console error message and a symbolicated stack trace of the crash.

Comment: If i run in simulator it will be fine and no crash. But When i run on device it crash. At first it show my keyboard during 1 or 2 seconds and then dismiss my keyboard and show standart. And nothing log in console. Only this - 2014-10-20 14:19:23.976 Keyboard[2840:189251] Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions from 2189: (null)

Comment: I try to debuq and have Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
also I have this 
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

Comment: Today I understood what happend. In my console i saw this message from didreicememorywarning:
2014-10-24 12:09:12.418 Keyboard[4633:438239] Received memory warning.
2014-10-24 12:09:12.429 Keyboard[4633:438239] MYKEYBOARD
What can I do with this? Can you help me please?